# Macro Produces Different Results If Clicking Screen While Running

Tags: vba, excel

I have two files (Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheets) that contain multiple fields of data. A macro I have will open both files, copy the data (without headers) from one of them, and paste that data underneath the data in the other file. Once the data has been combined, I save the combined file as a new workbook. A somewhat stripped down version of the code I have is below (sorry it's inefficient; I had only just begun VBA when I wrote it):

```
Sub Combine()

' Combine Macro

' Turn some things off to speed things up
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

' Set to directory where files to combine exist
ChDir "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Macro Work"

' Variable Declarations
Dim EmptyRow As Long
Dim FileA, FileB As String
Dim Day as Integer

Day = 1

' Loop and combine the two files for each day of the month (if they exist)
Do Until (Day > 31)

    ' Get FileA and FileB names
    FileA = "FileA" & Day & ".xls"
    FileB = "FileB" & Day & ".xls"

    ' Open files A and B; handle error if file doesn't exist
    On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=FileA
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            GoTo NoFile
        End If
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=FileB
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            GoTo NoFile
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Copy data from FileB and paste into FileA
    EmptyRow = Workbooks(FileA).Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy Workbooks(FileA).Worksheets(1).Range("A" & EmptyRow)

    ' Save combined workbook as FileName in Excel format
    Workbooks(FileA).SaveAs FileName:="CombinedFile" & Day, FileFormat:=51

    ' Close the workbooks
    Workbooks("CombinedFile" & Day).Close SaveChanges:=False
    Workbooks(FileB).Close SaveChanges:=False

NoFile:
    Day = Day + 1

Loop ' End of Loop

MsgBox "PAUSE - End of Macro"

End Sub
```

My problem isn't that that Macro won't run or throws an error. Rather if I run it and don't do anything else, I get one set of results. But if I run it and click on the VBA Editor Window while it's running, I get a different set of results.

Is it a known fact that you shouldn't do other things on your machine while your macro is running? Or have I neglected to add a piece of code that will keep the results of the macro consistent whether or not I sit and watch or am clicking the VBA Editor Window?

Thanks in advance, and let me know if I can provide further clarification.

Zachary

EDIT:

It's difficult to track down exactly what goes wrong with combining the files, but I can see that the number of lines differ. The combined file generated when I am clicking on the Editor Window has several thousand lines less than when I just watch it run. And I'll need to retract my earlier claim that I can consistently produce the same error. I can consistently reproduce an error, but the results may differ (i.e. maybe I'm missing only 4995 lines instead of 5000).

Liam, your response makes sense to me. However, I have a near identical Macro that skips this section:

```
'Copy data from FileB and paste into FileA
EmptyRow = Workbooks(FileA).Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy Workbooks(FileA).Worksheets(1).Range("A" & EmptyRow)
```

Since sometimes the files I work with only have "FileA" I don't combine anything and instead use a Macro to open the file and SaveAs FileFormat=51 and with a new name. Obviously that removes sections in the code where I select data in the file. Yet I still receive different results when clicking. What might be causing this?

Lastly, in addition to removing sections of code where `Selection` is used, is there a way to help prevent the user from messing up the results of the macro in this way?

Thanks again.

Comment: I've never heard of this. How do the results vary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its because you use:

```
Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
```

Just because screenupdate is false, doesn't mean excel isn't executing your clicks. You can't reference a selection and expect it not to change if you select something else

**Answers To Updated Question**

You can easily remove the need to "select" cells by defining them in a range and referencing your new range. This will remove the possibility of users clicking and messing up the flow of your script

```
'Copy data from FileB and paste into FileA
Dim R1 as Range
Dim R2 as Range

EmptyRow = Workbooks(FileA).Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Set R1 = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set R2 = Range(R1, R1.End(xlToRight))
R2.Copy Workbooks(FileA).Worksheets(1).Range("A" & EmptyRow)
```

This will do the same as your original code, without using select

Comment: This was my first assumption, too, but tihs doesn't seem to explain the stated problem: "if I run it and click on the VBA Editor Window..." Perhaps OP can clarify.

Comment: When you open your workbook in the code, because `ScreenUpdate = False` you dont see the editor window minimise and excel open, even though that is what has happened, so when your clicking, your actually clicking on the excel document

Comment: Hello, Liam. Thanks for your response. I think it makes sense to me. However, I had a couple questions which I've added to my question above. I've labeled my additions as "Edit:". Thanks.

Comment: Hello, David. I've tried to clarify my question a bit more. Let me know if it helps. Liam's response makes sense to me. However, I've added a couple of further questions to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to eliminate these problems is to reference the sheet in your calls (Sheets(1).Range(...)), and minimize selection (instead of .Select and then Selection., just put your Range.Copy or whatever you're doing).  A little more code, but more robust.

Comment: Hello, Matthew. Thanks for your suggestion. I'll be sure to avoid using Select and Selection in the future. However, I added a couple additional questions to my post. I've labeled it "Edit:". If possible, would you be able to comment on those? Thanks.

Comment: @Zachary: In regards to the difference in number of lines, are you still having this problem after you remove all of the Select/Selection statements?  I would think this would be related, because as you manually select something else while the macro's running, it can no long find the data it's looking for, thus producing a smaller result.  And when you ask about preventing the user from messing up the results, are you talking about the user adding select statements to the macro?  If you're talking about the user clicking around, it should no longer affect the results when Select is removed.